# IO.FileNotFoundException but File should exist

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, io

I'm getting a suprising `FileNotFoundException` although i'm sure that the file exists.

I simply wanted to add Logfiles(`IO.FileInfo`) as attachments to an email, therefore i tried to check the length of every file to detect if they must be added/zipped.
**This works fine if these files already exist**. 
But if i've created them in this run, i get above exception when i try to check the length. It's oddly enough that i can write into these "not existing" files(actually `FileInfo.Exists` returns `false`) without a problem one line before.

Here is some code...

Creating one of the files in the constructor of a class named `Log`:

```
Me.LogFile = New IO.FileInfo(infoLogPath)
If Not LogFile.Exists() Then
   'tried to use `Using` on the Stream but that doesn't change anything'
   Using stream = Me.LogFile.Create()
       'close and dispose implicitely
   End Using
End If
```

I can write into the file without a problem:

```
Me.Log.WriteInfo("BlahBlahBlah...", False)
```

One line after i'm getting the exception on `LogFile.Length`:

```
If Me.Log.LogFile.Length <> 0 Then
    files.Add(Me.Log.LogFile)
End If
```

`Me.Log` is a custom logging-class object named `Log` that holds the reference to the `FileInfo` object.

This is `WriteInfo` in class `Log`, `LogFile` is the `IO.FileInfo`-onject:

```
Public Sub WriteInfo(ByVal message As String, ByVal finishLog As Boolean)
    Try
        Using w As IO.StreamWriter = Me.LogFile.AppendText
            If Me.WithTimestamp Then
                w.WriteLine(Date.Now.ToString(Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) & ": " & message)
            Else
                w.WriteLine(message)
            End If
            If finishLog Then w.WriteLine("__________________________")
            w.Flush()
            w.Close()
        End Using
    Catch writeLogException As Exception
        Try
            WriteError(writeLogException, True)
        Catch innerEx As Exception
            'ignore
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

---

Actually [@ShellShocks solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939893/io-filenotfoundexception-but-file-should-exist/6940101#6940101)  with [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx) was simple. Never heard of this function, strange that i get a FileNotFoundException when i don't refresh the file.

```
Me.Log.LogFile.Refresh()
```

Comment: Is D is mapped drive or physical drive?

Comment: what sort of app is this - Windows Service ? ASP.NET ?

Comment: `D` is a physical drive, this code neither works on a Win2008-server nor on my development pc(Win XP). Both have this physical drive. This will be a Windows-Service but so far for testing purposes it's a WinForm- App with only a start-button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try calling [FileInfo.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx) before FileInfo.Exists, or FileInfo.Length--these properties may be cached, so Refresh will get the latest value.

Comment: The exception won't occur on FileInfo.Exists(where i create the file) but on FileInfo.Length, but `Refresh` before `Length` does actually avoid the exception, but why? Thank you very much :)